# Desconexión por inactividad MariaDB

Tags: java, mysql, mariadb

Estoy con un caso muy raro; Estoy desarrollando 2 sistemas en Java Web y esta vez lo hice con MariaDB (venía usando MySQL). El sistema que tiene como base de datos a MySQL tiene su conector JDBC y sus drivers correspondientes y funciona super bien, el sistema que usa como base de datos a MariaDB funciona bien también(los dos corren en un servidor de aplicaciones con Tomcat y en Windows Server 2016). Como les comenté ambos funcionan bien pero el sistema que usa como BD a MariaDB(también tiene su JDBC propio de MariaDB) se desconecta pasando un tiempo de aproximadamente 12 horas, la aplicación corre pero no se conecta a la BD para realizar su logueo, debo reiniciar el Tomcat para que funcione. Eso no pasa con el sistema que corre con MySQL.

Comment: Para entender la conectividad ¿Cuántos equipos (físicos) son?¿Todos en red local?

Comment: Hola Sal, solo son 4 equipos. Como mencioné, el problema no se aplica a la sistema que está con MySQL.

Comment: ¿Todos en una misma red local?

Comment: Si, es una intranet.